# I have troubles with implementing distributions in python

Tags: python

I want to write the function `all_possible(word, n)` where `word` is string with no spaces in it, and `n` is number of `|`'s. I need to put `|`'s in  `word` so that my output is list of all possible strings with inserted `|`'s between characters.

Example:

```
letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
print(all_possible(letters, 7)
>> ['a|b|c|d|e|f|g|hijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'a|b|c|d|e|f|gh|ijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'a|b|c|d|e|f|ghi|jklmnopqrstuvwxyz'...]
```

This is what I have so far:

```
def all_possible(word, n):
    word = list(word)
    l = ['|'] * n
    k = 1
    for c in l:
        word.insert(k, c)
        k += 2
    word = ''.join(word)
    return word
```

Any help now?

Comment: can you provide the code which you have tried by yourself ?

Comment: Seems like this is an exercise for either school or that you're self learning. Have you done any research or tried to solve this on your own? We don't write code here we help with issues. Please show us your effort and then we can help.

Comment: Use the itertools module. In particular, `itertools.combinations`

Comment: So far I tried to list my string, and then I tried to combine it with other list composed of n |'s, and after that again join the list, but with no success.

Comment: Perhaps you could show your best effort.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: Downvote changed to an upvote for the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not going to be able to do this with a single loop. You can try using `itertools.combination()`. For example, `combos = combinations(range(1, 26), 7)` will give you an iterator that lists out all the indices of the letters you should insert the bar before (with the help of `enumerate` to keep track of how many letters you're adding:

```
letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

combos = combinations(range(1, 26), 2)

for indices in combos:
    l = list(letters)
    for i, n in enumerate(indices):
        l.insert(i + n, '|')
    print("".join(l))
```

Prints:

```
a|b|cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
a|bc|defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
a|bcd|efghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
...
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx|y|z
```

You can change the 2 to 7, but be warned, it is a lot of combinations.

You can also do this recursively with the insight that inserting a single bar at between each letter is a single loop. Inserting 2 bars is the same as inserting a bar and then doing the same for the string left after the bar.

```
def insert_bars(s, n):
    if n == 0:
        yield s
    else:
        for i in range(1, len(s) - n+1):
            for rest in insert_bars(s[i:], n-1):
                yield s[:i] + '|' + rest
l = list(insert_bars(letters, 7))
```

`l` is length 480700:

```
['a|b|c|d|e|f|gh|ijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
 'a|b|c|d|e|f|ghi|jklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
 'a|b|c|d|e|f|ghij|klmnopqrstuvwxyz',
 'a|b|c|d|e|f|ghijk|lmnopqrstuvwxyz',
 'a|b|c|d|e|f|ghijkl|mnopqrstuvwxyz',
 'a|b|c|d|e|f|ghijklm|nopqrstuvwxyz',
 'a|b|c|d|e|f|ghijklmn|opqrstuvwxyz',
 'a|b|c|d|e|f|ghijklmno|pqrstuvwxyz',
 ...
 'abcdefghijklmnopqr|s|t|u|v|w|x|yz',
 'abcdefghijklmnopqr|s|t|u|v|w|xy|z',
 'abcdefghijklmnopqr|s|t|u|v|wx|y|z',
 'abcdefghijklmnopqr|s|t|u|vw|x|y|z',
 'abcdefghijklmnopqr|s|t|uv|w|x|y|z',
 'abcdefghijklmnopqr|s|tu|v|w|x|y|z',
 'abcdefghijklmnopqr|st|u|v|w|x|y|z',
 'abcdefghijklmnopqrs|t|u|v|w|x|y|z']
```